# i want to make the a href active when i click on the li tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to do vertical dots navigation bar. i'm using ul li inside a href to the link.i want that the link will work when i click on the li not just a. i'm looking for something in css but i can't find.

```js
;(function ( $, window, document) {
 
 var pluginName = 'eavesdrop';
 var calls = 0;
 
 function Eavesdrop(nav, options){
  this.element = nav;
  this._name = pluginName;
  this._defaults = $.fn.eavesdrop.defaults;
  this.options = $.extend( {}, this._defaults, options );
  this.init();
 }
 
 $.extend(Eavesdrop.prototype, {
 
  constructor: Eavesdrop,

  init: function(){
   var clickParams = $.proxy(this.clickParams, this);
   var scrollParams = $.proxy(this.scrollParams, this);
   var structure = $.proxy(this.structure, this);
   this.buildCache();
   this.errors();
   this.scrollClick = this.navAnchor.on('click', clickParams);
   this.scrollStructure = $(window).on('load resize', structure);
   this.scrollWindow = $(window).on("load resize scroll", scrollParams);
   this.onScroll();
  },
  
  destroy: function(){
   this.unbindEvents();
      this.$element.removeData();
  },
  
  buildCache: function(){
   var selector = '.'+this.options.watchClass;
   this.$element = $(this.element);
   this.$body = $('body');
   this.$selector = $(selector);
   this.navAnchor = this.$element.find('a');
   this.selector = selector;
   this.activeClass = this.options.activeClass;
   this.targets = $([]);
   this.distances = $([]);
   this.selectors = $([]);
   this.anchors = $([]);
  },
    
  unbindEvents: function() {
     this.$element.off('.'+this._name);
    },
  
  errors: function(){
   var selectorAmount = this.$selector.length;
   var navAmount = this.$element.find('a').length;
   navAmount === selectorAmount ? this.universalAmount = navAmount : console.error('target to selector mismatch');
  },

  structure: function(){
   var self = this;
   this.$selector.each(function(i){
    i++
    var hash = self.navAnchor.eq(i - 1).attr('href').split('#')[1];
    $(this).attr('data-connect', hash); 
    var connect = $(this).data('connect');
    offset = $(this).offset().top;
    self.targets.push(connect);
    self.distances.push(offset);
    self.selectors.push(i);
   });
  },

  clickParams: function(data){
   var router = data.currentTarget.hash.split('#')[1];
   var target = this.selector + '[data-connect="'+ router +'"]';
   var targetOffset = $(target).offset().top;
   this.$body.trigger(router[1] + '-inView');
   this.$body.animate({ scrollTop: (targetOffset) });
  },

  scrollParams: function(){
   var d = $(window).scrollTop();
   var inView = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < this.universalAmount; i++){
    var scrollHeight = d - this.distances[i];
    scrollHeight < 0 ? inView[this.selectors[i]] = Infinity : inView[this.selectors[i]] = scrollHeight;
    var currentlyInView = Object.keys( inView ).map(function ( key ) { return inView[key]; });
    var min = Math.min.apply( null, currentlyInView );
    var viewPos = currentlyInView.indexOf(min);
   }

   if(this.$element.attr('data-active') != viewPos){
    this.$element.attr('data-active', (viewPos));
    this.$body.trigger('active.'+this._name);
   }
  },

  onScroll: function(){
   var self = this;
   self.$body.on('active.'+this._name, function(){
    var a = self.$element.attr('data-active') || 0;
    self.$element.find('.'+self.activeClass).removeClass(self.activeClass);
    self.$element.find('a[href*="'+ self.targets[a] +'"]').parent().addClass(self.activeClass);
    if(self._defaults.trackUrl == true){
     history.replaceState(undefined, undefined, "#"+self.targets[a]);
    }
  });

  }
 });

 $.fn.eavesdrop = function ( options ) {
  calls ++
  this.each(function() {
   if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
     $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Eavesdrop( this, options ) );
   }
  });
  if(calls > 1){
   $.fn.eavesdrop.defaults.trackUrl = false;
  }
  return this;
 };
 
 $.fn.eavesdrop.defaults = {
  watchClass: 'eavesdrop',
  activeClass: 'active',
  trackUrl: true
  };
 
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

```css
.full {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  line-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 40px; 
  font-family: 'Secular One', sans-serif;
}
  .full.one {
    background: #8CC9DC; }
  .full.two {
    background: #DEEBF7; }
  .full.three {
    background: #FFFAFA; }
  .full.four {
    background: #C5E0B4; }
    .full.five {
    background: #DFE2E6; }
    .full.six {
    background: #fff; }
    .full.seven {
    background: #33CCCC; }

.dotstyle {
 position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   right: 0;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.dotstyle ul {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 cursor: default;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}
.dotstyle-tooltip li {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 30px 16px;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
  background-color: #969696;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 2px solid #969696;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
 transition: transform 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;

}

.dotstyle-tooltip li a {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
 top: auto;
 left: -149%;
 padding: 0 10px;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 0;
 color: #fff;
 text-indent: 0;
 line-height: 2;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease, visibility 0s 0.3s ease;
 transition: transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease, visibility 0s 0.3s ease;
}

.dotstyle-tooltip li a::after {
 position: absolute;
 left: 100%;
 border-width: 6px;
 margin-top: -6px;
 border-color: transparent;
 content: '';
 pointer-events: none;
 top: 50%;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
 transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  
}
.dotstyle-tooltip li:hover {
 z-index: 100;
 
}

 .dotstyle-tooltip li:hover a{

 z-index: 100;
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0%);
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0%);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease;
 transition: transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.dotstyle-tooltip li.active {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
 transform: scale(1.2);
  background-clip: content-box;
   padding:3px;
   right:3px;
  }
.dotstyle-tooltip li.active a {
 left: -120%;
  
}
.dotstyle-tooltip #startLi.active,.dotstyle-tooltip #startLi:hover,.dotstyle-tooltip #startLi a {
 background-color: #FFC000;
}
.dotstyle-tooltip #startLi.active {

 border: 2px solid #FFC000;
}
.dotstyle-tooltip #startLi a::after{
border-left-color: #FFC000;

} 
.dotstyle-tooltip #firstLi.active,.dotstyle-tooltip #firstLi:hover,.dotstyle-tooltip #firstLi a {
 background-color: #ED7D31; 
}
.dotstyle-tooltip #firstLi.active {

 border: 2px solid #ED7D31;
}
.dotstyle-tooltip #firstLi a::after{
border-left-color: #ED7D31;

}
.dotstyle-tooltip #secondLi.active,.dotstyle-tooltip #secondLi:hover,.dotstyle-tooltip #secondLi a  {
 background-color: #C00000; 
}
.dotstyle-tooltip #secondLi.active {

 border: 2px solid #C00000;
}
.dotstyle-tooltip #secondLi a::after{
border-left-color: #C00000;

}
.dotstyle-tooltip #thirdLi.active,.dotstyle-tooltip #thirdLi:hover,.dotstyle-tooltip #thirdLi a  {
 background-color: #7030A0; 
}
.dotstyle-tooltip #thirdLi.active {

 border: 2px solid #7030A0;
}
.dotstyle-tooltip #thirdLi a::after{
border-left-color: #7030A0;

}
.dotstyle-tooltip #fourLi.active,.dotstyle-tooltip #fourLi:hover,.dotstyle-tooltip #fourLi a  {
 background-color: #44546A; 
}
.dotstyle-tooltip #fourLi.active {

 border: 2px solid #44546A;
}
.dotstyle-tooltip #fourLi a::after{
border-left-color: #44546A;

}
.dotstyle-tooltip #fiveLi.active,.dotstyle-tooltip #fiveLi:hover,.dotstyle-tooltip #fiveLi a  {
 background-color: #70AD47; 
}
.dotstyle-tooltip #fiveLi.active {

 border: 2px solid #70AD47;
}
.dotstyle-tooltip #fiveLi a::after{
border-left-color: #70AD47;

}
.dotstyle-tooltip #aboutLi.active,.dotstyle-tooltip #aboutLi:hover,.dotstyle-tooltip #aboutLi a  {
 background-color: #000; 
}
.dotstyle-tooltip #aboutLi.active {

 border: 2px solid #000;
}
.dotstyle-tooltip #aboutLi a::after{
border-left-color: #000;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>תפריט</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/component.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo&subset=hebrew,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Secular+One&subset=hebrew,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="dotstyle dotstyle-tooltip">
        <ul class="nav-fixed">    
            <li id="startLi" ><a href="#one">פתיחה</a></li>
            <li id="firstLi" ><a href="#two">קומה 1</a></li>
            <li id="secondLi"><a href="#three">קומה 2</a></li>
            <li id="thirdLi"><a href="#four">קומה 3</a></li>
            <li id="fourLi"><a href="#five">קומה 4</a></li>
            <li id="fiveLi"><a href="#six">קומה 5</a></li>
            <li id="aboutLi"><a href="#seven">אודות</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
   
   <div class="one full eavesdrop">פתיחה</div>
   <div class="two full eavesdrop">קומה 1</div>
   <div class="three full eavesdrop">קומה 2</div>
   <div class="four full eavesdrop">קומה 3</div>
      <div class="five full eavesdrop">קומה 4</div>
      <div class="six full eavesdrop">קומה 5</div>
      <div class="seven full eavesdrop"> אודות</div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.eavesdrop.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.top-nav').eavesdrop();
        $('.nav-fixed').eavesdrop();
       });
      </script>    
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that the problem is with the position of the link. On hover, you translate it with 50% to the left. Try to put the text inside the link into a `<span>`, and move that span instead of the link, while you let the link to resize itself and stay in position.

Comment: thanks @Nekomajin42 that was helpful